# Failed to make an http (get) request with cookies when crossing the domains

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cookies, axios, cors

(I'm amateur and new here. So I'm not sure whether this question is a stupid one)

---

The story is that, today I tried to make a get request from **front-end** (React, axios, xxx.com) to **back-end** (Nodejs, express, yyy.com), with two cookies:

cookie-1: AAA=aaa; path=/ domain=xxx.com

cookie-2: BBB=bbb; path=/ domain=xxx.com

But, you know, I failed.

---

Then I searched on Google and tried these suggestions:

1. [front-end](/questions/tagged/front-end) I add `axios.defaults.withCredentials = true` to the .jsx file.
2. [back-end](/questions/tagged/back-end) I add body-parser to the server.js file:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.text())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
```

3. [back-end](/questions/tagged/back-end) I add cookie-parser to the server.js file:

```
app.use(cookieParser())
```

4. [back-end](/questions/tagged/back-end) I add some access control rules to the server.js file:

```
app.all('*', function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", req.headers.origin)
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS')
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Cookie")
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true)
    next()
})
```

---

After the attempts above I was still unable to receive the cookies.

So I did some tests.

---

1. Keep the back-end code unchanged. Replace the front-end code with an api-test-tool. Through it the back-end server successfully received the cookies.
2. Keep the front-end code unchanged. Move the back-end server to the same domain as the front-end's (xxx.com). This time the back-end server received the cookies as well.

---

In my perspective of view, test 1 and test 2 separately proved my back-end and front-end code worked well. But the original problem still occurs, can anyone help me with it? I will be really, really appreciate to any of your help!

Answer (score 1):

The cookie's SameSite mode is Lax by default, which make client's requests include the cookie only when the method is "safe" (GET and HEAD methods).

So if you wanna use other methods like POST, PUT, DELETE with Lax mode cookie, you have to use same domain.

Or you can set the SameSite mode of cookie to None mode, which allows cookies to be included in every request whether or not it is CORS. but in this case, cookie's Secure option is mandatory.